# Python getting model estimator object from Sagemaker model.tar.gz (for prediction instance explanation)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have been using ELI5 and LIME lately to provide some insight on what's driving specific predictions. They both work by passing the estimator object and the observed feature values to the function and then returns the prediction explanation.

Can this be used similarly with Sagemaker predictions? In a perfect world, I would start up an endpoint, make predictions, then retrieve the actual estimator object from the model.tar.gz outpt and pass this to ELI5. But I would love to hear if this is even doable before I go down this rabbit hole (and any specifics for the approach)...

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, is LIME and ELI5 in correspondence to: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/lime.html?

I am not too sure on the approach, but I believe it might not be supported out of the box and might be based on the model itself as defined here: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blackbox/index.html.

Were you able to get ELI5 and LIME to work in your environment? If so, then it should be possible on SageMaker, although there might be some churn.